# Using async/await in request module Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to use async/ await in request module but I cannot get it to run. I need the response function to wait for the request to complete ( the request pulls from data in a search-bar in browser) I have tried using x = await res, which looks like its not allowed, I have also tried let x = await getStockX() to no avail. I understand the need for await so I no longer run into undefined, but have struggled to find it used in this particular setup.

```
function getStockX(getUrl){
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    request({
        url: 'https://stockx.com/api/products/' + getUrl + '?includes=market&currency=USD',
        method: "GET", 
        headers: stockxGETHeaders
      },
    async function(err, res, body){
    let x = await getStockX(); // does not work
    let x = await res; // does not work
    let json = JSON.parse(body)

    console.log(json)

    resolve(sku)

        }); 
    })
}
```

Comment: async/await is just syntactic sugar for Promise. request is a callback base library, therefore, async/await does not work on it.

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: In your specific case, you want to just use the `request-promise` package instead.

Comment: @Bergi thank you or clarifying, my problem then is why is it not waiting for the response to finish with resolve?

Comment: Awaiting `getStockX()` in there makes no sense as it would be a recursive call. `await res` does not make sense as `res` is not a promise. Did you try `console.log(err, res, body)`?

Comment: Btw it really should be `async function getStockX() { const res = await requestPromise({url: …}); const sku = JSON.parse(res.body); return sku; }`